# Normalization of Non-Normal Data to 0-1 for use in Multi-criteria Evaluation

Tags: normalization

I have four criteria I am using for a multi-criteria suitability analysis.

They have varying scales, so I have used min-max feature scaling to normalize each indicator on a scale of 0-1. I then calculated a composite score using euclidean distance from the origin.

When normalizing, do you need to consider the distribution of the data? Will having one indicator that is skewed towards 0 when normalized have an undesirable impact on my combined score?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Sorry, but the question is rather unclear. My blog post (how to ask a statistics question)[https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/?s=how+to+ask+a+statistics+question] may help you formulate a question that can be answered.

Comment: Far more important is to consider whether any of these arbitrary purely mathematical operations have any meaningful relationship to suitability: what data or procedures have you used to establish that?

Comment: There is a linear relationship between the actual values and suitability in all cases except one. For this one indicator, a value of 0 to 30 is not at all suitable, and 70 to 100 is equally suitable. Between 30 and 70 the relationship is linear. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Although it's not what I mean, it's useful information.  When the actual values have linear relationships to suitability, using the Euclidean distance (which is a non-linear function of them all) is virtually guaranteed to be a bad procedure.  But how do you know those variables have linear relationships to suitability?  Do you have data that includes actual suitability measurements?  If so, why not perform a regression or make some form of predictive model?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think for this exercise a predictive model to determine suitability is necessary. Based on expert input in the subject area we decided a linear relationship to suitability was an acceptable assumption. 

Could you expand on why Euclidean distance is a bad procedure? After I posted this thread I began wondering if Euclidean distance was a good choice for calculating the score. Based on the research I've done so far, Manhattan distance appears to be a better choice as it is less sensitive to outliers.

Comment: The Euclidean distance is explicitly a non-linear function of all its inputs.  In certain situations it could be approximated with piecewise linear functions, but that really doesn't overcome the inherent contradiction of using a nonlinear model to analyze relationships that are assumed to be inherently linear.